# Dummy account for app review in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I have uploaded an app for review in iTunes Connect. The apps login procedure is as follows:

User enters his/her mobile number. If the mobile number is new and not in the database, an One Time Password(OTP) is sent as an SMS over the phone to the user and he/she may login.

If the number is already in the database, the user gets directly logged in.

My question is that what should I mention in the dummy account details?

I have mentioned a mobile number that is already in the database so that the reviewer may login and browse my app. 
Should I mention the details about an entirely new user as sending OTP to US won't be possible?

Kindly guide.

Comment: Have you put these comments in the Notes for the reviewer? They may just have to contact you at the time of review. Do you have a way to create a code up front, tell them what number you entered and send them the code as well

Comment: Note that apps that require a user to enter personal information, such as a valid phone number, might not meet Apple's app review guidelines, and thus have a high risk of being rejected.

Answer (score 1):

here is an solution, if apple reviewer can't send OTP then just use this simple trick.

if app reviewer has a login ID/PASS but the OTP is required any of case then just create account for apple reviewer and set Static OTP on this particular account.

tell them ID/PASS and OTP. just simple

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add some registered phone number in "username" section of submit for review form, it will be approved for that procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's exactly what I did.